# How to select data from a row in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I'm trying to do is select data from a specific row only in a MySQL database with PHP. For example, lets say if USER1 is logged in, I want to grab that users data from the row in the database and display it on USER1's profile with PHP. How can I do this with PHP? Please help me as I'm new to MySQL!

Comment: You'll get more help if you can show [that you have tried to do something for yourself.](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you need.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE user ='$user1'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

look this tutorials:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p2.html

http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php_2.htm